# About boundary local time on reflecting brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

> Definition: A bounded measurable function $u$ on $\bar{D}$ is called a weak solution of the Neumann problem $N(D ; q, \varphi)$ if, for all $x \in \bar{D}$,
> $$
> M_{\varphi}^u(t)=u\left(X_t\right)-u\left(X_0\right)+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \varphi\left(X_s\right) L(d s)+\int_0^t q u\left(X_s\right) d s
> $$
> is a continuous $P^x$ martingale. Here $x \in \partial D$, and $L$ is the boundary local time of X.
>
> Assume that $u \in C^2(D) \cap C^1(\bar{D})$. Let $x \in D$ and define as usual
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & B_{\varepsilon}(x)=\left\{y \in R^d:\|x-y\| \leqq \varepsilon\right\}, \\
> & \tau_{\varepsilon}=\inf \left\{t>0:\left\|X_t-X_0\right\|=\varepsilon\right\} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> For a fixed $t>0$
> $$
> \sup _{0 \leqq u \leqq t} E^x\left[\left(\int_0^u|q|\left(X_s\right) d s\right)^2\right] \leqq 2 E^x\left[e_{|q|}(t)\right]<\infty .
> $$
> Thus, from the definition and the fact that $E^x\left[L(t)^2\right]<\infty$ we get that $\left\{M_{\varphi}^u(s)\right.$, $0 \leqq s \leqq t\}$ is a continuous $L^2$-bounded martingale. By Doob's optional stopping theorem, we have $E^x\left[M_{\varphi}^u\left(t \wedge \tau_{\varepsilon}\right)\right]=0$. Now if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, then $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset D$ and $\tau_{\varepsilon}<\tau_D$. Hence, for $0 \leqq t \leqq \tau_{\varepsilon}$, we have $L(t)=0$.

Question: This is taken from Probablistic approach to the Neumann problem by Pei Hsu, I am not sure boundary local time $L(t)=0$, is it \begin{align*}
L_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}1_{\left\{X_{s} \in \partial D \right\}}\,dL_{s},
\end{align*}, and $X_s \notin \partial D$ in this case?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. See here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248849/on-a-reflecting-brownian-motion-and-its-boundary-local-time/248918#248918 for some more discussion on local time for Neumann boundary and some references eg. "Some Potential Theory for Reflecting Brownian Motion in Holder and Lipschitz Domains" by Bass and Hsu.

Comment: Yes, that's the local time they are referring to. You can see their paper for matching notation.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Got it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just turning my comment into answer.

See [On a reflecting Brownian motion and its boundary local time](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248849/on-a-reflecting-brownian-motion-and-its-boundary-local-time/248918#248918) for some more discussion on local time for Neumann boundary and some references eg. "Some Potential Theory for Reflecting Brownian Motion in Holder and Lipschitz Domains" by Bass and Hsu.

That's the local time they are referring to. You can see their paper for matching notation.